# Как получить значение указателя, адрес через ссылку на указатель?

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки, адрес

Подскажите, как это работает? Почему именно так и в чём тут логика? При такой записи

```
 int a = 5;
 int* pa = &a;
 int*& paref = pa;
```

и попытке вывода
`cout << *&paref << endl;` Я получаю значение указателя, адрес. Но почему это так работает?
Но ещё более непонятно, что при выводе `cout << &paref << endl;` Я получаю адрес, где лежит указатель. С обычной ссылкой вроде понятно разные варианты вывода, а тут просто не могу себя объяснить почему именно так. Интересует именно c++.

Comment: *"С обычной ссылкой вроде понятно"* - ¿Тогда что непонятно в этой ситуации? Тут же вполне себе обычная ссылка. Опишите что по-вашему происходит на каждом шаге вычисления этих выражений, а то так не ясно, в чем затруднение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнём с того, что [ссылки в С++](https://ravesli.com/urok-88-ssylki/) **разыменовываются автоматически**. А значит, вот это "шаманство":

```cpp
cout << *&paref << endl;
```

работает так. Сначала, когда Вы написали `paref`, ссылка **уже разыменовалась**, т.е. на этом месте уже стоит указатель на `a`, содержащий значение адреса переменной `a`. Т.е. `paref == pa == &a`.

Потом Вы получаете адрес этого указателя с помощью оператора `&`. Т.е., по сути, `&paref == &pa`.

Теперь Вы применяете оператор `*`, тем самым разыменовывая адрес указателя `pa` и получая снова указатель `pa`. То есть `*&paref == *&pa == pa == paref`. Все эти четверо равны!

Таким образом, вместо строки

```cpp
cout << *&paref << endl;
```

можно написать

```cpp
cout << paref << endl;
```

и получить аналогичный результат.

После объяснений первой строки, думаю, со второй всё стало понятнее. Сначала Вы пишете `paref`, что уже разыменовывает ссылку. Т.е. `paref == pa == &a`.

Потом Вы берёте адрес того, что получилось, оператором `&`. Т.е. `&paref == &pa`. И тем самым как раз и получаете

> адрес, где лежит указатель

P.S. Напоследок небольшая справка по операторам работы с указателями и ссылками:

`*` – оператор разыменования указателя (получение того значения, которое лежит по адресу, записанному в указателе)

`&` – оператор получения адреса (возвращает адрес переменной или ещё чего-нибудь)

– оператор разыменования ссылки. Да-да, там ничего нет. Потому что **ссылка разыменовывается автоматически**.

P.P.S. Если что, заранее прошу прощения за такой жирный акцент на автоматическое разыменование ссылки, если Ваше непонимание было вызвано не этим. Просто, на мой взгляд, именно непонимание данного принципа вызвало у Вас непонимание всего механизма работы.